# need sphinx configuration for the non integer primary key

Tags: sphinx

i want to create `sphinx` search for following table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `books` (
  `productID` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `productName` varchar(256) NOT NULL,
  `ISBN` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `author` varchar(256) DEFAULT NULL,
  `productPrice` float(10,2) NOT NULL,
  `discount` float(10,2) NOT NULL,
  `brandID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `qty` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `status` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`productID`),
  KEY `status` (`status`),
  KEY `ISBN` (`ISBN`),
  KEY `author` (`author`),
  KEY `brandID` (`brandID`),
  KEY `books_index` (`productName`)
) ENGINE=innodb DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

I can't alter the `productID` column in above table..

i have dependency tables for `author` and `Brands`

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `authors` (
      `authorID` ini(11) NOT NULL,
      `author_name` varchar(256) NOT NULL
      PRIMARY KEY (`authorID`)
    ) ENGINE=innodb DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `brands` (
      `brandID` ini(11) NOT NULL,
      `brandName` varchar(256) NOT NULL
      PRIMARY KEY (`brandID`)
    ) ENGINE=innodb DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

please some one provide configuration for `sphinx` search.

i am using following config.

```
source src1
{
        type                    = mysql


        sql_query               = SELECT CRC32(productID) as productid,productID,productName,ISBN,brandID,author FROM sapna_ecom_products

        sql_attr_uint           = productID
        sql_field_string        = ISBN
        sql_field_string        = productName
        sql_field_string        = brandID
        sql_attr_multi         = uint brandID from field; SELECT brandID,brandName FROM sapna_ecom_brands
        sql_attr_multi         = uint author from field; SELECT authorID,author_name FROM sapna_ecom_authors

        sql_query_info          = SELECT productID,productName,ISBN,brandID,author  FROM sapna_ecom_products  WHERE CRC32(productID)=$id
}
```

I am getting results if i search by `productName` but not for `author` and `brand`

My aim is to get the results if user search any by `productName` or `author` or `brand`

Please somebody provide me suitable configuration..

thanks..

Answer (score 3):

One way would be to just generate a integer key

```
sql_query = SELECT CRC32(productID) AS id,...
```

because you can't now relate that back to the real productID, you could store prodctID in a attribute so you get it back in query results.

Its possible you might get collisions with CRC32,

A quick query to check

```
CREATE TABLE test (id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY) SELECT CRC32(productID) FROM books;
```

If that works, you good to go,

if not, will have to use a better hashing. See also

http://greenash.net.au/thoughts/2010/03/generating-unique-integer-ids-from-strings-in-mysql/

---

Alternativly

```
sql_query_pre = SET @id := 1;
sql_query = SELECT @id := @id + 1 AS id,...
```

Comment: Thanks for you replay..its helped me lot.. i have edited my question. could u plz provider me configuration..

Comment: i admit dont really know stackoverflow ettiquete but the extra stuff you added is not related to the original question - so should start a new question. hint: should probably use sql_joined_field not integer attributes